# neo4j LOAD CSV with Tabs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load a csv and create nodes in neo4j 2.1.0 using the following:

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM "file://c:/temp/listings.TXT" 
AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
CREATE (p:person { id: line[0] });

The columns are separated using 0x9 (tab) characters. But the created nodes have the entire row content in the id.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post an example of the file?

Comment: how large is the csv file? a cleanup with python/bash beforehand might just do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

try `FIELDTERMINATOR '\\t'`
that's what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try casting toint(line[0]) since the default type when importing is string.

Answer (score -2):

Open your csv file with notepad++ and try to delete the (") or to replace them with spaces.

I had the same problem but when I removed all the characters " it worked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRw2P.png)