# Import TSV data into Neo4j using import tool

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, py2neo, csv, data-import

I am trying to import a large dataset into my local Neo4j instance. I am trying to use the import tool but so far with no success.

Due to the size of my data I can't use Cypher or "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS" approach (also my data has no headers).

I am trying to use the import tool with the following statement:

```
neo4jimport --into C:\...\my_database --nodes    C:\...\Authors_header.csv,C:\...\Authors.csv --stacktrace --delimeter TAB
```

My file is a .CSV file but the values are TAB separated. My header file is of format:

```
authorID    author_name
```

And my main (dummy in example) file looks like:

```
1   Banana
2   Apple   
3   Pear
4   Potato
5   Tomato
```

I tried the dummy file with commas and with semicolons and the approach works fine but using the TAB both properties get joined into one, so after import I have nodes with just one property named:

```
authorID author_name
```

Due to the size of my files I can't just replace TABS with commas. I tried changing the delimeter to '\t' and other combinations but no go.

Also I would like to know if it possible to add a static label to each node when it is created even if the label is not read from the data file.

I was thinking of using a different approach, with Python and py2neo, if the import tool doesn't pull it.

I am using Neo4j 2.2.3 community edition on an average portable machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo: it is not `delimeter` but `delimiter`, see neo4jimport --help

Update to 2.2.5 to get the latest release with the highest performance.

Your header should probably be:

`authorID:ID  author_name`

and you should also provide `--id-type integer`

You can provide a label for all nodes on the command-line: `--nodes:Author`

Comment: I hate it when that happens (typo), spent the whole afternoon on that. Thanks for the quick reply - works like a charm.

Comment: can we use different delimiters for `LOAD CSV` command as well?. Update: it seems like YES we can https://stackoverflow.com/q/23701507/3209523